# Clear ssl client certificate state from javascript in firefox 33.0.2 (removed Proprietary window.crypto)

Tags: firefox, caching, ssl, certificate, client-certificates

I'm looking for a way to clear the SSL client certificate cache in Firefox as a kind of "log out" functionality so that the server does not recognize me anymore via the client certificate the next time I connect to it. The solution from [clear-ssl-client-certificate-state-from-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724489/clear-ssl-client-certificate-state-from-javascript)

```
 if (window.crypto) window.crypto.logout();
```

does not work anymore in the current version of Firefox.

[With firefox 33.0.2 the Proprietary window.crypto properties/functions are removed](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/33.0.2/releasenotes/)

How can I do this in the current Firefox version?

Answer (score 5):

You can enable `window.crypto` by setting

```
dom.webcrypto.enabled = true
```

in `about:config`.

However there is no out of box replacement for FF 33.
It seems like Mozilla rolled it back in FF34, so it should be available there again.

**EDIT**:
There is an replacement:
http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/

Comment: If you're already familiar with the WebCryptoAPI I would appreciate a code snippet that achieves what has been asked for. Thanks!

Comment: I could not find such functionality in the w3 draft.

Comment: This functionality is not present in FF 47 (no `dom.webcrypto` in `about:config`). See also https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225487

Answer (score 1):

There is not an official solution for FF & Chrome. for a unofficial solution see: [Web Crypto API — An Authentication of Data and People in SSL](http://html5.creation.net/webcrypto-api/)