# what is the replacement or alternative for window.crypto.logout after firefox 33

Tags: firefox, logout, window.crypto

previous day, we are using window.crypto.logout to clear the client mutual SSL authentication.

After firefox 33, does anyone know how can we clear the client SSL authentication ?

thank you

Comment: same question as:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855289/clear-ssl-client-certificate-state-from-javascript-in-firefox-33-0-2-removed-pr

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled across the same issue. For the record: this functionality has been removed, according to

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225487:

> That functionality is no longer exposed to web content.